# A water mark in the graph/figure when export from SAS

Tags: sas, watermark

We need to put a water mark in the graphs and figures when export reports to rtf and pdf files from SAS. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found here the tutorial: http://support.sas.com/kb/24/319.html

```
proc template;
   define style watermark_pearl;
     parent=styles.pearl;
  class body from document /
          background=_undef_     
          backgroundimage="draft.png";  
   end;
run;

title;
options nodate nonumber;
ods _all_ close;
ods pdf file="watermark.pdf" style=watermark_pearl notoc;

proc report data = sashelp.class;
run;

ods pdf close;

/* Use this PROC TEMPLATE code if using SAS® 9.3 or earlier */
proc template;
    define style watermark_printer;
     parent=styles.printer;
         class body from document /
          background=_undef_
          backgroundimage="draft.png";
   end;
```

You may have to modify the path for `backgroundimage` and for `ods pdf file`. For example: `/project/myproj/files/mypdf.pdf`. It depends on your OS.

For rtf format it seems not to be possible to add a watermark in older versions: https://communities.sas.com/t5/ODS-and-Base-Reporting/Using-ODS-RTF-to-add-a-watermark/td-p/1002

For SAS 9.4 here is a possible way shown to add a watermark with `ods tagsets.rtf`: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odsug/69832/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p19rpsb989jyadn1kgunyh4t8g0e.htm

```
options (watermark='<specify the path to your watermark here>');
```

Comment: That post is from 2006, there may be a way today.

Comment: @Reeza: Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Hi Reeza, Thanks! I do find two articles talking about how to add watermark in rtf. http://www.lexjansen.com/pharmasug/2010/CC/CC08.pdf and https://pharmasug.org/proceedings/2012/CC/PharmaSUG-2012-CC06.pdf